# Выбрать из таблицы по двум параметрам с разными приоритетами?

Tags: sql

Есть примерно такой запрос:

```
SELECT cell-1 FROM photoes WHERE cell-2=6 [OR|AND] cell-3=7;
```

Из таблицы должна выбираться строка, если в ее ячейке cell-2 значение равно 6. Если такой нет, должна выбираться строка у которой cell-3=7. Это можно сделать двумя запросами с проверкой.
А можно ли сделать один запрос?

Comment: А чем не нравится

    SELECT cell-1 FROM photoes WHERE cell-2=6 OR cell-3=7

Comment: Наверное надо XOR использовать вместо OR иначе если оба условия есть то будет две строчки

Comment: @Чад оказывается, воскресенье -- очень тяжёлый день. Откуда такие мысли? XOR гарантирует, что выполняется только одно из условий. Из условий задачи я такого требования не уяснил.

Comment: @alexlz, по условию задачи второе условие должно срабатывать только если первое не верное. Т.е. нам нужна только одна строка или у которой cell=8 или у которой cell !=8 and cell = 10. Хотя наверное всё намного интереснее. По идее мы должны выбрать все строки с 8 мёркой, а если таких нету то все строки с 10сяткой. И простой OR в данном случае нам не поможет.

Comment: Мне нужно не "хотя бы одно" и не "либо/либо". Мне нужно, чтобы выбиралось по условию "cell-2=6", а в случае, если такого не найдется, выбрать первое "cell-3=7"

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov что значит "первое"? 

@Чад в случае XOR мы имеем, что при cell-2=6 строка не будет выбрана, если cell-3=7. Это противоречит условиям @oleg_ismaylov

Comment: А если с 8 есть, то нужно одно или все?

Comment: "первое" - значит любая строчка, в которой в поле "cell-3" стоит значение "7".

Comment: @alexlz, xor в данном случае бессмысленно т.к. одновременно cell не может быть равно и 8 и 10 :-) Ваша правда. OR тоже не то :-)

Comment: @Чад. Тут не совсем понятно, что имел в виду ТС. cell-3 -- это выражение (поле cell минус 3) или имя поля. Во втором случае Ваша ирония пролетает.

Comment: "cell-3" - имя ячейки/поля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно ли мы Вас поняли:

Из всего скопа мы выбираем строки у которых `"cell-2" = 6 or ("cell-2" != 6 and "cell-3" = 7)`

или если в скопе нет НИ ОДНОЙ ЗАПИСИ с `"cell-2" = 6` тогда мы выбираем первую запись с `"cell-3" = 7` ?

В первом случае условие говорит само за себя во втором случае надо сделать примерно так:

```
select * from (
select cell-1 from photoes where "cell-2" = 6

union

select cell-1 from photoes where "cell-3" = 7 limit 1 ) limit 1
```

Если уж совсем правильно надо ещё добавить сортировку чтобы гарантировать результат
И избавляемся от union

```
select cell-1 from photoes where "cell-2" = 6 or "cell-3" = 7
order by if("cell-2" = 6,0,1)
limit 1
```

Comment: Второй вариант. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov. union излишен. Такой результат может быть получен запросом
 (синтаксис mysql)

    select 0 as ord, `cell-1`
      from photoes
      where `cell-2` = 6 or `cell-3` = 7
      limit 1

Различия будут, если записи, удовлетворящие условию `cell-3` = 7 идут раньше записей с `cell-2` = 6 при отсутствии сортировки. Это непонятная ситуация, но я телепатией не владею, увы.